# Magento2 configurable product and simple product link tables

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I mistakenly saved hurt all of my products catalog losing the links between simple products and configurable products, anyone knows the tables to be reset or if I can do it programmatically?

Comment: Can try Export / Import?

Comment: No, just tried but magento2 reimport products unlinked in the same way as i 've export them